# Removing words with 'pop'

Tags: python

I need to remove a word from a list, then I display the words - which I can do fine.
But then when I remove the second word and append the word removed earlier it cannot find the list.

```
replword = words.pop(9)
except IOError:
    print("WARNING: The text file cannot be found. The program will not run without error.")

'while menu = true'
    try:
        threeByThree() #function: threeByThree
        #suffle words
        #remword = words[9]
        #words = random.shuffle(words)
        print(remword)
        newword = replword
        words.append(newword)
        threeByThree()
        #firstNineWords = words[:9]
        #lastWord = words[-1]
        words[random.randrange(9)] = lastWord #generate integer between 0 and 9
        print("")
        threeByThree
    except NameError:
        print("WARNING: Because the file is not found, the   list 'words' is not defined.")
```

I have tried the code in multiple different orders and I still get the name error saying the list is not defined, when it is defined when it pulls words in.

I need to be able to assign 2 variables to both words, the one that is removed and added and then the second one removed - which after this problem I can do myself.

Comment: You do realize that by having 13 lines of code (5 of which are now commented) protected by `try/except NameError` means that any object you misspell the name of in that entire section will cause your program to print "WARNING: Because the file is not found..." etc. which will not be true?

Comment: What is `threeByThree` and why on the last line is it not `threeByThree()`?

Comment: This code cannot be ran, please provide a *full running example*. One thing that I can point though: `threeByThree` is a function but after the last print it's called as if it's a builtin.

Comment: threeByThree is a function containing   print (words[0:3])
    print (words[3:6])
    print (words[6:9])

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to bug hunting 101**. You need to step back and try and clarify the problem you are having. The code you provided is an incomplete portion of some larger script.  As the comments above, you are referencing threeByThree as a function and as a builtin.  Further you are not passing anything to that function, assuming that words is global and always available.  The best thing you can do is open up a REPL console and mess around.

```
>>> listOfWords = ["My","dog","has","fleas","and","ticks","and","worms","he","al
>>> listOfWords
['My', 'dog', 'has', 'fleas', 'and', 'ticks', 'and', 'worms', 'he', 'also', 'smells']
>>> removeditem = listOfWords[4]
>>> removeditem
'and'
>>> listOfWords
['My', 'dog', 'has', 'fleas', 'and', 'ticks', 'and', 'worms', 'he', 'also', 'smells']
>>> removeditem = listOfWords.pop(4)
>>> listOfWords
['My', 'dog', 'has', 'fleas', 'ticks', 'and', 'worms', 'he', 'also', 'smells']
>>> removeditem
'and'
>>> anotherremoveditem = listOfWords.pop(1)
>>> listOfWords
['My', 'has', 'fleas', 'ticks', 'and', 'worms', 'he', 'also', 'smells']
>>> anotherremoveditem
'dog'
>>> listOfWords.append(removeditem)
>>> listOfWords
['My', 'has', 'fleas', 'ticks', 'and', 'worms', 'he', 'also', 'smells', 'and']
>>> listOfWords.append(anotherremoveditem)
>>> listOfWords
['My', 'has', 'fleas', 'ticks', 'and', 'worms', 'he', 'also', 'smells', 

'and', 'dog']
    >>>>>> def threeByThree(words):
...   print(words[:3])
...   print(words[3:6])
...   print(words[6:9])
...
>>> threeByThree(listOfWords)
['My', 'has', 'fleas']
['ticks', 'and', 'worms']
['he', 'also', 'smells']
>>> threeByThree(listOfWords[9:])
['and', 'dog']
[]
[]
>>>
```

Of course if you mistype something, you can see the error message

```
>>> threeByThree(sistOfWords[9:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sistOfWords' is not defined
```

So if your call to threeByThree()  is referencing a variable *words*  which you did not pass, and the Try/Except loop is catching the exception  you are going to get the wrong error message.

```
>>> def three():
...   print(words[0:3])
...
>>> three()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in three
NameError: global name 'words' is not defined
>>>
```

As I've told students in the past: A program does exactly what it is told to do, not what you want it to do.